# `std::enable_if` instantiating type parameter when predicted has failed causing error

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, enable-if

I have a function that I want to toggle on and off using `std::enable_if` on its return type. Like so:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>  
auto bob(T v) {
    return v.size;
    //return 0;
}

template<typename T>
struct the_type {
    using type = decltype( bob( std::declval<T>() )   )>; 
};

template<int I>
auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<I != 0, typename the_type<int>::type> {
    return {}; 
}

template<int I>
auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<I == 0, int> {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
    foo<0>();
}
```

However the problem I am having is that even when the predicate of `std::enable_if` is `false` it still tries to instantiate the type parameter, which in turn invokes another function using `decltype`. That function does not work with specified type.

Please note the above code is a test case that demostrates the same problem I am having with a much large code base.

I've tried adding in `std::conditional_t` but that like `std::enable_if` tries to instantiate both of its template parameters.

The behaviour I'd like is for the compiler to recognise that `0 != 0` is false, and either not instantiate the type parameter or simply ignore any compile errors.

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `enable_if` in a different place it will work better:

```
template<int I, typename = std::enable_if_t<I != 0>>
typename the_type<int>::type foo()
```

Comment: Doesn't work neither [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/se948vjGd).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a work around, but I'd still be keen to hear other ideas, as this feels crusty:

I can change `the_type` to the following:

```
template<typename T, bool = std::is_same_v<T, int>>
struct the_type {
    using type = decltype( bob( std::declval<T>() )   );  
};


template<typename T>
struct the_type<T, true> {
    using type = std::nullptr_t;
};
```

**Note** in the real code, `std::is_same` is replace by a more complex predicate - using `std::is_same` to demonstrate the behaviour.

In an ideal world, I wouldn't need to provide the predicate, perhaps the failure of bob would be enough for it to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your have several similar issue:

- `bob` is not SFINAE friendly. i.e `bob<int>` produce an hard failure (failure happens in the body, not in declaration).
- `the_type` is not SFINAE friendly neither but anyway `the_type<int>::type` doesn't depend of template parameter (so error doesn't come from substitution).

You can delay instantiation to avoid hard error

```
template<typename T>  
auto bob(T v) { return v.size; }

template <typename T>
struct the_type {
    using type = decltype( bob( std::declval<T>() )   )>; 
};

template<int I>
auto foo()
-> typename std::conditional_t<I == 0,
                               std::type_identity<int>,
                               the_type<int>
                              >::type
{
    if constexpr (I == 0) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return {};
        // Following would still be an hard error (independent of I)
        // return typename the_type<int>::type{}; 
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qMso6e4xh)
Notice that `foo<1>` would still be an hard error.

Or make all type/function SFINAE friendly:

```
template<typename T>  
auto bob(T v) -> decltype(v.size)
{
    return v.size;
}

template<typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct the_type;

template<typename T>
struct the_type<T, std::void_t<decltype( bob( std::declval<T>() )   )>>
 {
    using type = decltype( bob( std::declval<T>() )); 
};

template <int I, typename T>
struct always
{
    using type = T;
};

template <int I, typename T>
using always_t = typename always<I, T>::type;

template<int I>
auto foo()
-> std::enable_if_t<I != 0, typename the_type<always_t<I, int>>::type> {
    return {}; 
}

template<int I>
auto foo() -> std::enable_if_t<I == 0, int> {
    return 5;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K55M5YW4r)